Conormal module of a commutative Koszul algebra
Does the conormal module $I/I^2$ of a commutative Koszul algebra $A=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$ have a linear minimal free resolution? Is there a formula for the Betti numbers of $I/I^2$, or, even better, a way to construct the resolution from the Koszul dual $A^!$?
I have put this question also on stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4935855
